# Self registration error message

Tags: account, error-messages, user-registration

I want to implement a self registration process for communities. The problem is when I submit my entries in the registration form, the error message

"Your request cannot be processed at this time. The site administrator has been alerted"

is displayed.

I know that there are solutions in the web. One of them I think is very helpfull:

http://carvingintheclouds.blogspot.de/2014/09/your-request-cannot-be-processed-at.html

For the first, the third and the last problem I did the necessary steps to solve them. But I'm not sure what to do to solve the second problem.

"
The Account Owner does not have a User Role assigned. If you're creating a new Account record on the fly, especially in B2C situations, you need to make sure you assign a default account owner that also has a User Role value. Any role will do, and you can use either a workflow rule or Apex to perform the assignment."

Can anybody help me what I have to do in detail? I use a dev org with me as account owner.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user need to be assign a role. So go to User> select your user > Edit and i Role give it any role(eg CEO) Then Save it.

[image]

[image]

It will solve your problem

Comment: Okay thank you, that works. The error message doesn't occur now. Now I have the problem that there is the error message: Error: Error occurred while loading a Visualforce page.

Comment: @nwolny that you need to post a separate question to get better response. Also if this solve your problem you can accept my answer.